# click on div 1, open new content. click on div 2 open content of div1

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a lots of boxes with different content.

If you click on the first box, you can see a popup-box with more details. 
If you click on the second, third, etc. boxes you have to see the details of the boxes.

My problem: If I click on box no. 2 I see the details of box no. 1.

HTML:

```
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>

<div id="openDiv" class="openDiv case1 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x50/ffffff/000000" alt="#" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 content">
    <p>Some Stuff here</p>
  </div>
  <div id="light" class="white_content">
    <p>Case 1! More Stuff. Say Hello!</p>
    <a href="#" class="openDiv" id="closeDiv">Close</a>
  </div>
q</div>

<div id="openDiv" class="openDiv case2 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" alt="#" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 content">

    <p>Some Stuff here</p>
  </div>
  <div id="light" class="white_content">
    <p>Case 2! More Stuff. Say Hello!</p>
    <a href="#" class="openDiv" id="closeDiv">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
function clickCase() {

  $(".openDiv").click(function() {
   $("#light").toggle();
   $("#fade").toggle();

  });
 $("#closeDiv").click(function() {

   $("#light").toggle();
   $("#fade").toggle();
  });
}
```

Here is the whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/jvynbq1u/

Comment: id's must be unique.

Comment: You should be use with different `id`. the id's are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update function

```
function clickCase() {
  $(".openDiv").click(function() {    
        $(this).find("#light").toggle(); 
        $("#fade").toggle();
  });  

  $(".closeDiv").click(function() {
        $(this).find("#light").toggle();    
        $("#fade").toggle();   
  }); }
```

and change classes  in HTML to close

```
<div id="openDiv" class="openDiv case1 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x50/ffffff/000000" alt="#" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 content">
    <p>Some Stuff here</p>
  </div>
  <div id="light" class="white_content">
    <p>Case 1! More Stuff. Say Hello!</p>
    <a href="#" class="openDiv closeDiv" id="">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="openDiv" class="openDiv case2 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" alt="#" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 content">

    <p>Some Stuff here</p>
  </div>
  <div id="light" class="white_content">
    <p>Case 2! More Stuff. Say Hello!</p>
    <a href="#" class="openDiv closeDiv" id="closeDiv">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and don't forget to add "closeDiv" into class of elements with this ID. It is working for me on JSFiddle. **http://jsfiddle.net/jvynbq1u/9/**

Please also use classes, when you want to add one function on more elements, not id. One specific ID should be only for one element on page.

Comment: For me too, just if you close the second one, the "#fade" doesn't fade out.  No matter if it's an ID or a class.

Comment: It is working fine without a lot of changes in code.

Comment: Thanks, but now it doesn't work with div1 ? Strange ;-)

Comment: Lol, I am sorry, there was a mistake about selector in js. Fixed.

Comment: there are still duplicate id's

Comment: @iHasCodeForU i have not time for update all occurrences in html, how can you see in JS, I do not using IDs so ... They just can be removed from HTML

Comment: wrong #light is a duplicate id that you're still using.

Comment: really ? It is hard to change "#" to "." and cut IDs and paste to class attr ?

Answer (score 1):

> You should be use with different id. those id's are same as unique id.

***Try this code  and check with my demo:***

```
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>

<div id="openDiv1" class="openDiv case1 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x50/ffffff/000000" alt="#" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 content">
    <p>Some Stuff here</p>
  </div>
  <div id="light1" class="white_content">
    <p>Case 1! More Stuff. Say Hello!</p>
    <a href="#" class="openDiv" id="closeDiv">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="openDiv2" class="openDiv case2 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" alt="#" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 content">

    <p>Some Stuff here</p>
  </div>
  <div id="light2" class="white_content">
    <p>Case 2! More Stuff. Say Hello!</p>
    <a href="#" class="openDiv" id="closeDiv">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>



function clickCase() {

  $("#openDiv1").click(function() {
    $("#light1").toggle();
    $("#fade").toggle();

  });
  $("#openDiv2").click(function() {

    $("#light2").toggle();
    $("#fade").toggle();
  });
}


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  clickCase();

});
```

### [Demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvynbq1u/2/)

Comment: Yeah, I see, thanks. But I will have 9 boxes or more. That's not so smart to write for every box a new function, isn't it?

Comment: You will go to use JQuery accordion control or other plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [conditional ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```js
function clickCase() {
  $(".openDiv").click(function() {
    ($(this).attr('id') == "openDiv") ? $("#light").toggle() : $("#light1").toggle();
    $("#fade").toggle();
  });

  $("#closeDiv, #closeDiv1").click(function() {
    ($(this).attr('id') == ("openDiv" || "closeDiv")) ? $("#light").toggle() : $("#light1").toggle();
    $("#fade").toggle();
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  clickCase();
});
```

```css
.openDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.case1 {
  background-color: #00b5b5;
}

.case2 {
  background-color: #4c4c4c;
  color: white;
}

.black_overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 1001;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.white_content {
  color: #292929;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 70%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
<div id="openDiv" class="openDiv case1 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x50/ffffff/000000" alt="#" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 content">
    <p>Some Stuff here</p>
  </div>
  <div id="light" class="white_content">
    <p>Case 1! More Stuff. Say Hello!</p>
    <a href="#" class="openDiv" id="closeDiv">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="openDiv1" class="openDiv case2 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" alt="#" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 content">
    <p>Some Stuff here</p>
  </div>
  <div id="light1" class="white_content">
    <p>Case 2! More Stuff. Say Hello!</p>
    <a href="#" class="openDiv" id="closeDiv1">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the case of multiple elements you can use ternary chaining

Example:

```
$(this).attr('id') == "openDiv") ? $("#light").toggle() : 
$(this).attr('id') == "openDiv1" ? $("#light1").toggle() : 
$(this).attr('id') == "openDiv2" ? $("#light2").toggle() : 
$("#light3").toggle();// keep expanding till you reach enough.
```

It is also a good idea to save `$(this).attr('id')` in a variable if you need to check multiple elements.

Alternatively you could use a switch case.

Example:

```
switch($(this).attr('id')){
  case "openDiv": $("#light").toggle(); break;
  case "openDiv1": $("#light1").toggle(); break;
  //go on for how many you would need.
}
```

Note: I have made the id's unique.